# Get multiselect values on the server side in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, get, server-side, multi-select, selectedvalue

I have the following tables PurchaseQuery, Suppliers. But PurchaseQuery can have more than 1 Supplier, so added a third table PurchaseQuerySupplier to keep both tables' IDs.
[image]

I have PurchaseQuery form in which I added a multiselect list to select multiple Suppliers.

```
                            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.PurchaseQuerySuppliers, new MultiSelectList(Suppliers.AsEnumerable(), "ID", "Name"), new { @class = "chosen-select"})
```

But in my Action Controller I get null object of PurchaseQuerySuppliers. Although I can comma separated Supplier values in FormCollection, but I want to get PurchaseQuerySuppliers as an object inside PurchaseQuery in Action Controller.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a view model that will solve the problem.

```
public class PurchaseSupplierViewModel
{
    public List<int> SelectedSupplies { get; set; } 
    public List<SelectListItem> Suppliers { get; set; } 
}
```

and your controller:

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    List<Supplier> SupplierList = (get all Suppliers from DB here) 
    var model = new PurchaseSupplierViewModel()
    {
       Suppliers = SupplierList.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                            Text = x.Name,
                        }).ToList()
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(PurchaseSupplierViewModel model)
{
    // model.SelectedSupplies will contain the selected Supplier IDs here
}
```

then the view:

```
@model PurchaseSupplierViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedSupplies, Model.Suppliers, new { @class = "chosen-select" })
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it with some test examples:

Model:

```
    public class SuppliersModel
    {
        public List<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
        public string[] PurchaseQuerySuppliers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Supplier
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Actions:

```
    public ActionResult ListTest()
    {
        var model = new SuppliersModel();
        model.Suppliers = new List<Supplier>();
        model.Suppliers.Add(new Supplier { ID = 1, Name = "Name1"});
        model.Suppliers.Add(new Supplier { ID = 2, Name = "Name2" });
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ListTest(SuppliersModel model)
    {
        string[] selectedItems = model.PurchaseQuerySuppliers;

        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@model SuppliersModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.PurchaseQuerySuppliers, new MultiSelectList(Model.Suppliers.AsEnumerable(), "ID", "Name"), new { @class = "chosen-select"})
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```